# Access Angular2 translation from component or service

Tags: angular, internationalization

I am currently in the process of translating my first Angular2 application based on the guidelines in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html

The examples only always show how to apply the `i18n` attribute to template code and how the template's code is then internationalized.

How would I access localized text from the component's code (the `.ts` file) or inside a service? I need this for interaction with some JavaScript libraries I am using, where I need to call a JavaScript function with the localized text.

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11405

Comment: DId you take a look at [ng2-translate](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate)

Comment: Unfortunately it seems exactly like #11405. I did not find this issue upon research, and I was under the impression that something that fundamental needs to be available.

I wanted to stay offical "angular2", but i18n seems too incomplete for now.

Answer (score 12):

If you were using [ng2-translate](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate) module, you could just inject `TranslateService`:

```
constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) { }
```

and use its `get(translationKey: string)` method returning an `Observable`.

```
this.translateService.get('stringToTranslate').subscribe(
    translation => {
        console.log(translation);
    });
```

Comment: Seems like `ng2-translate` is still the way to go for now. Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel I need to translate response values which have nearly 50 columns to translate form ngOnInit hooks, i need to specify each key can you provide better resuable way `this.productSrevice.getProduct().subscribe(response => { this.cols = [ { field: 'response.data.productId', header: this.translateService.instant('Home.productID')}, { field: 'response.data.productName', header: this.translateService.instant('Home.productName') }, etc ]; console.log(this.translateService.instant('Home.productID')); }`

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the [attribute translation feature](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html#!#translate-attributes).

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-sandbox',
    templateUrl: 'sandbox.html'
})
export class SandboxComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input()
    public title: string;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('Translated title ', this.title);
    }
}
```

From the parent component template:

```
<app-sandbox i18n-title title="Sandbox"></app-sandbox>
```

It is a workaround, but still, I think it's the cleanest one so far. It gives you access to the translated `title` within `ts`.

Comment: But this is for a `Component`. This won't work in a service, will it?

Comment: I'm actually using it in a service, passing the `title` to the service using a setter within ngOnInit. Well yeah so the solution is component specific, the service knows about it from the component, which is not that clean after all :)

Comment: I agree it is the cleanest available solution. Although I still hope the official i18n tools are going to be improved.

Answer (score 0):

```
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) { }

  this.translate.get(this.pageTitle).subscribe((text:string) => {
      this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
        title.setTitle(this.translate.instant(text))
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to detect on Language change use below code ,
pass your title key

```
this.setDocTitle('dashboard.title');

setDocTitle(titleKey: string) {
  this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
    this.translate.get(titleKey).subscribe((text:string) => {
    this.titleService.setTitle(this.translate.instant(text));
  });
  }); 
}
```